# Archive and compress set of very similar png images

Tags: linux, compression, png, tar, archive

I have tens of thousands of png images that are very similar to each other and I would like to archive them and compress them in the process. I am aware that png files can barely be compressed because it already is a compressed file format. In my case though, these are similar to each other which is why I thought that there may be some program out there that takes advantage of that. Any hints?

EDIT: example image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/a2HYg.jpg

Comment: Hard to say without seeing them.

Comment: `tar` + `zstd` with options to use a large window?

Comment: @Shawn using `tar --use-compress-program="zstd --long" -cf images_long.tar.zstd images`, but didn't make the resulting file smaller (<1%).

Comment: @MarkSetchell here is an example: https://imgur.com/a/N9csZZH

Comment: The sample image begs the question why are you using PNG format at all.

Comment: @MarkSetchell are you suggesting something like jpeg? lossless compression is what we need though. Or do you have a different, better lossless compression in mind?

Comment: Your sample image looks like a photograph. JPEG is designed to store photos - *"Joint **Photographic** Experts Group"*. PNG is more typically used for computer-generated, non-photo-realistic things like diagrams and presentation graphics and so on. A JPEG of your image is virtually indistinguishable and already 70-80% smaller. Why do you think you need lossless?

Comment: @MarkSetchell It is dataset for autonomous driving with which neural networks are trained for object detection etc. When compressing these images using lossy compression it may introduce unwanted artifacts and I would have to quantify the error in some way. It is simply easier to work with lossless compression.

Comment: NN seem to work fine with jpeg, looking at research others did online. Alternatively, there may be a way to create a lossless video from the stream of png images saving the base image and only subsequent changes. Not an expert on any of this, but sharing a thought.

Comment: @oleksii Lossless video compression may be a good lead, thanks.

Comment: I came across this question while researching something similar, and posted my answer on another similar question on SuperUser. In short, I decompressed the PNGs to raw data, which compressed better when the data was very similar. I am not sure how well my findings translate to your kind of images (my tests were done on screenshots) but it is worth a try: https://superuser.com/questions/1311850/compressing-many-similar-large-images/1828892#1828892

Answer (score 0):

Video compression also tries to take advantage of similar images to compress smaller. You should try a lossless video compression codec such as WebM.

Comment: This is a good idea. Ideally I would like to be able to compress these png images (eg. as you suggested using lossless video compression) but I also want to be able to extract them again to the original format.

Comment: You can always extract and recompress to png. That's what would have to happen, regardless of the format. If you're getting a compression advantage over png, then it's not png.

Answer (score -1):

I think it does not matter for PNG or other lossless formats how similar they appear for humans when you want to compress them (in a single tar for example). Only a few bits or pixels difference make each image mathematically a totally different object. When a high compression of zstd cannot do the trick, you won't need to search anymore. You cannot outperform entropy. There is a mathematical limit on compression, and zstd comes close to that.

Comment: I do not think this is the right approach. Given for example two images of the same scene, where every pixel is only shifted in some direction one could only save the first image then save the offset to the second image.

Comment: That's a practically impossible scenario, because in no way can a camera be moved exactly a column of pixels. You will always have an angle, and even if this only occurs in one single row the idea of a kind of "only recalculate one column and keep the rest as the known bloc" is busted all over the image.